# Cannot install ruby with ASDF

Tags: ruby, macos, asdf-vm

I'm trying to install ruby 2.2.10 with ASDF without success. I tried to find on my own why it's this happening now. Not sure if some brew update it breaks it or what.

Here I share the output of the install:

```
asdf install
elixir 1.10.2-otp-22 is already installed
elm 0.18.0 is already installed
istioctl 1.4.7 is already installed
Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/ecd0c6ffb493dd06707d38b14bb4d8c2288bb7033735606569d8f90f89669d16
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
Installed openssl-1.0.2u to /Users/murbano/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.2.10

Downloading ruby-2.2.10.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.10.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.10...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.10 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.6 using ruby-build 20200520)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/47/wxs46t2s6db9fh1zv640mpdr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921205118.64211.ty44rI
Results logged to /var/folders/47/wxs46t2s6db9fh1zv640mpdr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921205118.64211.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
encoding.c:825:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_str_change_terminator_length' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_str_change_terminator_length(obj, oldtermlen, termlen);
        ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [encoding.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Also tried with:

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)" asdf install
elixir 1.10.2-otp-22 is already installed
elm 0.18.0 is already installed
istioctl 1.4.7 is already installed
Downloading ruby-2.2.10.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.10.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.10...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.10 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.6 using ruby-build 20200520)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/47/wxs46t2s6db9fh1zv640mpdr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921210737.34707.yrr2le
Results logged to /var/folders/47/wxs46t2s6db9fh1zv640mpdr0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921210737.34707.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
encoding.c:825:2: error: implicit declaration of function 'rb_str_change_terminator_length' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        rb_str_change_terminator_length(obj, oldtermlen, termlen);
        ^
compiling enumerator.c
1 error generated.
make: *** [encoding.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

```
brew --prefix openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
```

I installed XCode, restarted, something it's stoping the install but I'm not sure why.

That happened after uninstalled ruby to do a new clean install.

Comment: You got `implicit declaration of function xxx is invalid in C99`. It looks like your compiler is too new for the old code it is trying to compile. I'm not sure how, but if you can sneak in compiler flags into the build process with asdf, then you could try the ones suggested in the error message, which should turn the error into a warning instead, allowing the compilation to complete.